# how to bubble up a bool from inner contained class to outer contains class

Tags: c#, boolean, value-type

I have 3 classes:

```
class A 
{
    public B b = new B();    
    public bool flag {get; set;}
}

class B
{
   piblic C c = new C();
}


class C
{
   public void foo()
    {
  //iterates a dataTable with column "someBoolCondition"
  // I want to set A's bool to true, after the first record that has 'true' in column
  //"someBoolCondition". Thus is thought to avoid bool memebers in each class.
    }
}
```

What it the best way set A's flag to 'true' from C's foo?

TIA

Comment: Could you exemplify your description with some code?

Comment: Please paste some code, it is not clear whether `B` is a nested class of `A` or `A` contains an object of type `B`, and likewise the relationship between `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C can fire an event every time C changes its own bool. Your A can subscribe to event and update itself. You can also pass an abstracted interface of A to b and C for letting them push the change directly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution again, simplest form architectual point of view, but it's not clear to me if it's acceptable in your specific case, is just to have a `static` property in A class.

```
public class A 
{
     private static bool failed = false; 
     public static bool Failed {get {return failed;} set {failed=value;}}
}
```

and somewhere in the code in your foo() function:

```
foo(...) 
{
    //failure happens! 
    A.Failed = true;
}
```

This is easy and clear, but it depends if it's acceptable from you app architectural point of view.

Hope this helps.